# How can I configure Resharper's language level for ECMAScript 6?

Tags: visual-studio, ecmascript-6, resharper-9.1

Consider the image below:

[image]

- How can I configure Resharper's language level for ECMAScript 6?

Comment: Click the spanner to the left and change the inspection severity to "Do not show"

Answer (score 149):

In Resharper 2016 this has been renamed to ECMAScript 2015. It's available under

Resharper Options | Code Editing | Javascript | Inspections

[image]

Comment: my problem here is that this is seemingly across all projects... my situation involves different levels for different projects. anyone know how to set this on a project basis?

Comment: Yes, get a different machine for each project. That should work.
You should post that as a separate question, but I think there is probably an answer somewhere already.

Comment: *get a different machine for each project*? Really? That's ridiculous.

Comment: @MrTristan may have figured it out by now, but for completeness this can be set per project using Resharper->Manage options and pick the project team-shared level.

Answer (score 7):

ReSharper 9.2 uses ECMAScript version specified in Project Properties | Typescript Build | ECMAScript version. [image]