# Configure Resharper 10 level for ECMAScript 6 not working

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-2005, resharper-10.0

Warning: ECMASript 6 feature. your current language level is ECMAScript 5

Even though I have correctly configured resharper 10 to use ECMASript 6.

I have looked at thse articles without finding any ansers

- [How can I configure Resharper's language level for ECMAScript 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995066/how-can-i-configure-resharpers-language-level-for-ecmascript-6)
- [How to use ECMAScript 6 syntax with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034668/how-to-use-ecmascript-6-syntax-with-visual-studio-2013)
- [Typescript Feature 1.5. Current language level is 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277413/146-errors-typescript-feature-1-5-current-language-level-is-1-4)

[image: ECMASript 6 feature. your current language level is ECMAScript 5]

[image: Reshaper Settings]
[image: Reshaper 10]

Comment: That file is `.js`, not `.ts`. Did you configure the language version in the JavaScript section?

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks, totally missed that?